# I tried is to include electron-usb library into my electron-project

Tags: node.js, electron

When I execute npm start with require('electron-usb') in my index.js file an error occurs in the console:

Cannot find module 'node_modules\electron-usb\build\Release\electron-v0.36-win32-x64\usb_bindings.node'

Comment: We could use a little more info. I assume you've already run `npm update` and `npm install` to update your dependencies?

Comment: yes and also npm install -g electron and npm install node-pre-gyp -g